# Pass param to ssh user@server bash --login -c FILE.rb PARAMS

Tags: bash, ssh

I need run bash ruby script over ssh on remote server:

```
# $1 - get params from local bash session
ssh user@server bash --login -c FILE.rb $1
```

FILE.rb now recive no any params
bash --login is need for ruby loading (over RVM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to enclose the whole command in quotes to make sure it is not interpreted by `ssh`:

```
ssh user@server "bash --login -c \"FILE.rb $1\""
```

If it does not work, verify, that all the params you need are really in variable `$1` by `echo`-ing it before the `ssh` call.

Minimal working example:

```
param="--version";
ssh user@server "bash --login -c \"git $param\""
```

Comment: $param="--version";
ssh user@server "bash --login -c git $param".  Error: =--version:  command not find

Comment: corrected to param="--version"; ssh user@server "bash --login -c git $param" but result is still "git" not "git --version"

Comment: Try to quote also the argument of bash, as I modified the answer, but note that the quotes needs to be escaped as I write.

Answer (score 1):

`-c` only takes a single argument, so more quoting is required:

```
ssh user@server bash --login -c "FILE.rb $1"
```

Comment: $param="--version";
ssh user@SERVER bash --login -c "git $param"
ERROR: =--version: command not finded

Comment: @mixo `param="--version"`, not `$param="--version"`.

Comment: i correct to param="--version" but execute result is still "git" without "git --version"